# Strange Code first Migration behavior, or IIS issue?

Tags: ef-code-first, signalr, entity-framework-migrations

Ok, so the background is this.

I have created a hardware controller for a fingerprint reader, and a web application that allows users that have scanned in to do things in the web application. The web application was created using Code First, and the communication is done through signalr 2.0 The problem that I am having is this. Everything works beautifully for about a day, this used to be about half a day, but in IIS 7.0 I changed the idle time on the application pool to 200 mins, but I am still getting an error at random times on the web server, I have managed to have extended the amount of time that is stays running. However, what confuses me, and why I cannot seem to get a handle on what is happening is that when it does go down;

A) I do not know why? (I am leaning towards a timeout somewhere)

B) The error message is the same one you get when you make a change to the database structure and forget to use Database-Update from the package manager console, Yet no one is changing the database.

c) If you leave it alone it will fix itself, and I do not know why or how.

Has anyone seen behavior like this? and if so what caused it and how did you fix it? Or can anyone offer how I can debug this?

Thanks so much for any help!

Kelso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update on this issue, it turns out that the IIS server had been set to only a single CPU and a single thread, (VMare setting) and that thread was getting hung, and could not create a new thread to continue processing, once we updated the cpu's and increased the thread count to 5, everything works like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is "The model backing the 'YourContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database" you could try to catch that exception and log the content of the following method and compare it to the return value of the method in Application_Start or whenever it worked for you.

```
((System.Data.Entity.DbContext)(context)).InternalContext.QueryForModel(0)
```

The method gives you a XML representation of your database schema.

Comment: Its not that particular issue, that is just the error that comes back, that error can change from instance to instance, sometimes its also that there are conflicting changes when the item is being saved.